# How to have URLs with dashes in Kohana 3.x

Tags: controller, kohana, action, kohana-3

I need to have a URL such as http://example.com/controller/my-page-with-dashes

How can I have such as URL in Kohana? I tried creating a controller and name the action `myPageWithDashes` like in the Zend Framework but that didn't work. Any idea how it should be done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copy the file `system/classes/kohana/request/client/internal.php` to your application folder - `application/classes/kohana/request/client/internal.php`. Then change **line 106** from:

```
$action = $request->action();
```

to:

```
$action = str_replace('-', '_', $request->action());
```

Comment: You should never edit the system files. Otherwise you get problems when upgrading your sites to new versions. Extend the client/internal file instead, and make amends in your application folder. Extending and editing core files can be done this way due to cascading files: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files

Comment: Thanks @Luwe, I reimplemented it by extending the core file.

Comment: There are better ways to do this. See the answer from zombor to see how.

Comment: This is not the way you should be changing how the routes work.

Comment: Everybody is throwing around links to the docs. But does any of you guys have a concrete solution to make it work? The lambda route creates all sorts of maintenance problems **because it rename the action** (i.e. the action is sometime known as "my-action", sometime as "my_action"). The solution I propose keeps the name of the action consistent throughout the app. So if you have to patronize other users on what should or shouldn't be done, at least provide some concrete solutions.

Comment: Laurent: I post a solution with examples

Answer (score 1):

No, you just need to specify a regex parameter in your route.

Read the docs on routes, it explains this: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#regex

Comment: Just as an aside to this, my suggestion would be more appropriate if you aren't relying on auto-translation of - to _ for controller/action names. I prefer more explicit routing, so I suggested this. If you really want things auto-translated, lambda parameters are the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just as zombor said change the regex of the route:

Route:

```
Route::set('default', 'controller/<url>)', array('url' => '[-a-z0-9]+'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'page',
        'action' => 'index',
  ));
```

Controller:

```
Class Controller_Page {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $url = $this->request->param('url');
    }
}
```

`array('url' => '[-a-z0-9]+')` This part changes what is allowed in the url param.

Comment: Your method routes all requests to one action, it will work for very simple application but for complex one it's useless

Comment: @matino: It is meant to be an example for the op. While I understand there are better ways to do this I'm only trying to achieve what the op wants. It only routes all requests made to `domain.com/controller/this-is-a-slug` to that defined controller so I'm not sure why I deserve a downvote.